# Mysql - Joining Multple Tables to set up a concat, to update a single column in a table

Tags: mysql

I have four tables; that share keys, and i want to update one of the columns, with a concat of two of these key fields
e.g.

```
Table| Person | Account | Transaction | TxnRecord
------------------------------------------------
Keys |PersonID|AccountID| Txn ID      | RecordID
     |        |PersonID | AccountID   | TxnID
```

So i initially tried to created a temp column to hold the new concated Record ID made of the PersonID and AccountID. I also selected the other IDs to verify that the query was behaving as it should.

```
SELECT p.PersonID
     , a.AccountID
     , t.TxnID
     , r.RecordID
     , CONCAT(p.PersonID,"-", a.AccountID) as NewRecordID
  FROM Person p
  JOIN Account a
    ON a.PersonID = p.PersonID 
  JOIN Transaction t
    ON t.AccountID = a.AccountID
  JOIN TxnRecords r
    ON t.TxnID = r.TxnID;
```

Now the trouble is with my understanding of UPDATE INNER JOIN in the Mysql Library.
I've tried, but couldn't get it to work.

Here is my initial attempt

```
UPDATE TxnRecord
SET TxnRecord.RecordID = CONCAT(Person.PersonID,"-",Account.AccountID)
(((INNER JOIN Transaction ON Transaction.TxnID = TxnRecord.TxnID)
INNER JOIN Account ON Transaction.AccountID = Account.AccountID)
INNER JOIN PersonID ON Account.PersonID = Person.PersonID)
```

Please help me understand if Update Inner Join is capable of something like this, or is there another approach I should look into?
Thank you.

Comment: I note that in your original (erroneous) SELECT, you referred to both Record and TxnRecord. Is this significant?

Comment: Also, it's a massive mistake to construct an id this way - disappointing that others haven't mentioned that

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for your comment. I understand what you are saying. Yes, it is a bad way of constructing an ID; but I had to simplify the data structure for this post to anonimize and also make the understanding of my problem easier for everyone, including myself. Also the Record/TxnRecord is a typing error. my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SET` clause comes after all the joins. And there's no need for parentheses around the joins.

```
UPDATE TxnRecord
INNER JOIN Transaction ON Transaction.TxnID = TxnRecord.TxnID
INNER JOIN Account ON Transaction.AccountID = Account.AccountID
INNER JOIN PersonID ON Account.PersonID = Person.PersonID
SET TxnRecord.RecordID = CONCAT(Person.PersonID,"-",Account.AccountID)
```

The parentheses aren't needed in the `SELECT` query, either.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I'm running into a couple of errors, cause on my version of Mysql, it was asking to have the table I'm trying to update aliased, which was easy, but the hardest problem at the moment is this SQL Error (1054): unknown column. I keep checking and rechecking, and all the columns exist on my table and hold data.

Comment: I mistyped one of the column names, try now.

Comment: I don't think its a problem of your query. What I did was I took your original query, and translated it into my own data structure. This was because I had to anonymize my post, and to simplify the problem to its essentials. so my error (1054)  should not be a problem of how you mistyped.

Comment: If you're getting "unknown column" then you entered an incorrect table or column name somewhere.

Comment: I managed to fix it was an addressing problem. But a new problem has occurred. 
so the new RecordID is the same for all of rows affected. WHat is happening is that the new concatenated ID is pulling from the Account ID of the first entry. Is there a Syntax in Mysql that would pull only the information from the relevant row?

Comment: I'm getting the correct RecordID from the Select Query I made however. Would this be a logic error with the Update command?

Comment: This query should be using the person ID and account ID from the related row, I'm not sure why it isn't. Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data?

Comment: Ok, so it seems I've over simplified my tables and data for this question, and the size of the application is just what was wrong. Nothing on your code, it was all on my Implimentation.